# django automatic creation of the form from the model

Tags: django, django-forms

is there a possibility from a model like:

```
class foo(models.Model):
   a = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   b = models.ForeignKey(foo2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
   c = models.DateField(name='c', blank=True, null=True)
   d = models.EmailField(name='d')
   e = models.BooleanField(default=False, name='e')
```

automatically generate a form like:
where for all attributes (self-written) an attribute must be in the form. the name parameter could then be the label.

```
class fooform(forms.ModelForm):
   a = models.CharField(name='a1', max_length=64)
   b = models.ForeignKey(foo2, name='b1', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
   c = models.DateField(name='c1', blank=True, null=True)
   d = models.EmailField(name='d1')
   e = models.BooleanField(default=False, name='e1')

   class Meta:
        model = foo
        fields = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
        labels = { 'a': 'a1',
                   'b': 'b1',
                   'c': 'c1',
                   'd': 'd1',
                   'e': 'e1'}
```

I found out that I can run through all attributes

```
 attributes = [i for i in dir(foo)]
```

and that the `wsgi.py` is called with runserver. but I can't find a way to generate an attribute / field in the form for each attribute of the model.

---

Edit:

Fady's Cube's solution goes in the right direction. the form class then looks like this:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = Foo
            fields = '__all__'
```

I just notice a strange behavior in the automatic label-name assignment.
For example if I have the model class:

```
class foo(models.Model):
     m_cls_foo_doo = models.BooleanField(default=False, name='cls_foo.doo')
```

then the model creates the label-name for the field: "`Cls foo.doo:`", i.e. it capitalizes the first letter, omits the underscore and puts a colon at the end. is there a reason here?

```
<tr><th><label for="id_cls_foo.doo">Cls foo.doo:</label></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="cls_foo.doo" id="id_cls_foo.doo"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Take a look at [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```py
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: even if the question is an answer, i haven't replied to the answer yet because i've encountered a problem since a few days, see above.